# Faster MySQL Join for DISTINCT records

Tags: php, mysql

After reviewing the related questions, none of them seem to address mine, so here goes:

I have two tables containing Course information.  One table [course] holds, currently, nearly 25k records with fields such as CourseName, CourseCode, Term, Instructor, etc.  The second table [courseCatalog] holds merely the CourseCode and CourseName.

My application allows users to pull up an instructor and approve the courses from a list that they are allowed to teach.

I built a search with auto-suggest (jQuery Ajax Object -> PHP file -> MySQL and back) to find courses.  When they are returned the user can click the course to mark (Another Ajax call to PHP & MySQL) it as an approved course for the instructor.

The problem is, there are some courses in the larger table that are not in the smaller table, and vice versa (eliminating that problem is a much harder issue based on where the data actually comes from, i digress)

If I join the tables on any particular field, certain courses are left out.  LEFT JOIN still seems to yield the same problem because I'm forced to JOIN ON a field.

If I simply call to both tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT course.CourseCode, course.CourseName
FROM course, courseCatalog
```

The query takes FOREVER which renders the search function useless, as it takes to long to load the suggestions.

I'd like to get a DISTINCT list of courses, in order, whether they appear in the 'course' table or the 'courseCatalog' table...with great haste :)

Any suggestions?  Have I overlooked something simple?  Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Query you say takes forever is doing a completely redundant cartesian join where you are generating a whole load of additional rows (Number of rows in course multiplied by Number of rows in courseCatalog) then removing them again with `DISTINCT` to leave you with the original contents of the `course` table. (Same result as `SELECT DISTINCT CourseCode, CourseName FROM course`)

To get a distinct list of CourseCodes and CourseNames from both tables you can use the `UNION` operator.

```
SELECT CourseCode, CourseName
FROM course
UNION /*Will ensure DISTINCTness*/
SELECT CourseCode, CourseName
FROM courseCatalog
ORDER BY CourseCode, CourseName
```

Comment: Beautiful, I was sure there was some operator or syntax that would knock this out and it blazes now.  Thanks Martin